# Elasticsearch cannot find standalone reserved characters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-analyzers

I use Kibana to execute query elastic ([Query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)).

When i search a word include escapable characters (reserved characters like: '\', '+', '-', '&&', '||', '!', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '^', '"', '~', '*', '?', ':', '/'). It will get expected result.
My example use: '!'

[image]

But when i search single reserved character. I got nothing.
[image]
Or:
[image]

How can i search with single reserved character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR You'll need to specify an analyzer (+ a tokenizer) which ensures that special chars like `!` won't be stripped away during the ingestion phase.

---

In the first screenshot you've correctly tried running `_analyze`. Let's use it to our advantage.

See, when you don't specify any analyzer, ES will default to the [`standard` **analyzer**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#analysis-standard-analyzer) which is, [by definition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#_definition_4), constrained by the [`standard` **tokenizer**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) which'll strip away any special chars (except the apostrophe `'` and some other chars).

Running

```json
GET dev_application/_analyze?filter_path=tokens.token
{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "text": "Se, det ble grønt ! a"
}
```

thus yields:

```json
["Se", "det", "ble", "grønt", "a"]
```

This means you'll need to use some other tokenizer which'll preserve these chars instead. There are a [few built-in ones available](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html), the simplest of which would be the [`whitespace` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html).

Running

```json
GET _analyze?filter_path=tokens.token
{
  "tokenizer": "whitespace",
  "text": "Se, det ble grønt ! a"
}
```

retains the `!`:

```json
["Se,", "det", "ble", "grønt", "!", "a"]
```

So,

#### 1. Drop your index:

```json
DELETE dev_application
```

#### 2. Then set the mappings anew:

(I chose the [multi-field approach](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers) which'll preserve the original, standard analyzer and only apply the `whitespace` tokenizer on the `name.splitByWhitespace` subfield.)

```json
PUT dev_application
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "splitByWhitespaceAnalyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "splitByWhitespace": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "splitByWhitespaceAnalyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### 3. Reindex

```json
POST dev_application/_doc
{
  "name": "Se, det ble grønt ! a"
}
```

#### 4. Search freely for special chars:

```json
GET dev_application/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "name.splitByWhitespace", 
      "query": "*\\!*",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

Do note that if you leave the `default_field` out, it won't work because of the `standard` analyzer.

**Indeed, you could reverse this approach, apply `whitespace` by default, and create a multi-field mapping for the "original" indexing strategy (-> the only config being `"type": "text"`).**

---

Shameless plug: I wrote a [book on Elasticsearch](https://elasticsearchbook.com/?ref=so) and you may find it useful!

Answer (score -1):

[Standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)

> The standard analyzer is the default analyzer which is used if none is specified. It provides grammar based tokenization (based on the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm, as specified in Unicode Standard Annex #29) and works well for most languages.

so no token is generated for hyphen. If you want to find text with hyphen, you need to look into keyword fields and use wildcard for  full text match

```
{
  "query": {
     "query_string": {
       "query": "*\\-*"
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: My search function will split words to single word and search with AND condition. And the last word will use wild card Example:
- My input: hello - guy
=> spllit "hello",  "//-", "guy*"
- Expect result: hello - guy nice to meet you...

Comment: @VietDinh I am not able to understand your query.  if this is your  text in document "hello - guy nice to meet you..." do you want to search for "hello - guy " and want this document returned?

Comment: Yes. But, i also want to get document which content is "hello some one - abc guy nice to meet you.." will be return.

Comment: @VietDinh is it required that "-" should be present or a  document with "hello guy" will be returned too

Comment: yes, it require "-" in document! document with "hello guy" must be not return.

Comment: I have done sample for your solution. But it do not work.